# Затемнение фона по клику

Tags: javascript

Ищу решение для задачи. Есть небольшой кусок js кода открывающего-закрывающего боковую панель навигации. Нужно изменить-дописать код так, чтобы при открытии.sidenav фон затемнялся, при закрытии возвращался к исходному состоянию. Код лежит здесь — http://javascript.ru/forum/site/70434-zatemnenie-fona-po-kliku.html

Comment: в конце `body` добавьте `div` блок, которому задайте ширину и высоту по 100%. `position: fixed`, `background: rgba(183, 183, 183, .6);`, `disaply: none;`, `z-index: 100`. Вашему sidebar-у задайте свойство `css` - `z-index-101;`

И при открытии бара делайте появление блока, тобишь добавляйте `disaply:block`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom --

Comment: Получилось, спасибки большие!